# How to write css for a div under a div which specific id which is itself under a div with specific class?

Tags: html, css

I have some div structure:

```
<div class="row-fluid Editor-container">
    <div id="menuBarDiv" class="row-fluid">
      <div class="btn-group">
          <div class="btn-group" title="Fonts" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
          <div class="btn-group" title="Paragraph Format" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
           <div class="btn-group" title="Font Size" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
      </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

Now I want to write a CSS where:-

`div of class="btn-group"` inside `div id="menuBarDiv"` inside `div class="Editor-container"` would have css like this:-

```
.btn-group::before, .btn-group::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline;
}
```

**How can I do that?**

Comment: `id` is already specific, so you would write like `#menuBarDiv .btn-group`... I don't understand what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to style `.btn-group` in `#menuBarDiv` in `.Editor-container`?

You would do that by `.Editor-container > #menuBarDiv > .btn-group::before` or `.Editor-container #menuBarDiv .btn-group::before`.

**The difference**: My first code **must** follow the exact hierarchy, you defined there. The hierarchy in the second code can differ in some way, there can be another id or class in between #menuBarDiv and .btn-group for example, it doesn't matter if they are direct children or parents.

More information about the topic: https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

**Notice**: As kukkuz already pointed out, the id is already specific, make sure you really have to use the child selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Editor-container > #menuBarDiv > .btn-group::before, .Editor-container     > .menuBarDiv > .btn-group::after {
content: "";
display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details to your answer as this post has been found in low quality post. Code only and 'try this' answers are discouraged as it doesn't provide any searchable content and why people should 'try this'.

Comment: What @Paritosh is pointing out here: Saswat asked a pretty basic question mostly about CSS, so just throwing a piece of code at him might not be as helpful as explaining him the situation and provide additional resources in my opinion. If this would be a very complicated question, which indicates a deep understanding of the technology from the person that is asking, and the answer is just self explaining, I would agree with you, when you say it's enough to post, what you posted.